# Global variable in a module, read after multiple write

Tags: django, python-3.x, global-variables

I am working on Django project, but this question could also be Python generic. Answers that utilize specific Django feature can also be accepted.

I am trying to define a global variable as a dict in a module. I require that this variable can be accessed by other module. The difficult part is, this global variable can be set/update multiple times by indefinitely many other modules at build time. After all the set/update, the variable can be read to set some other global variables in a fixed number of modules. How should I make sure that all the read happen after the set/update?

Demo code:

1. I want to have a `GLOB` at `setting.py` of module `m`:

At m/setting.py:

> GLOB = dict()

2. Some other modules (indefinitely many, assume they are `p`, `q` and `r`) will need to update this variable:

At p/config.py:

> from m.setting import GLOB
>
> GLOB['p'] = 1

At q/config.py:

> from m.setting import GLOB
>
> GLOB['q'] = 2

At r/config.py:

> from m.setting import GLOB
>
> GLOB['r'] = 3

3. Two modules (fixed many, assume they are `a` and `z`) will need to read from this variable and do other stuff:

At a/config.py:

> from m.setting import GLOB
>
> A_GLOB = [k for k in GLOB if GLOB[k]%2]

At z/config.py:

> from m.setting import GLOB
>
> Z_GLOB = [k for k in GLOB if not GLOB[k]%2]

For the above example, how may I ensure that the `A_GLOG` is `['p', 'r']` and `Z_GLOB` is `['q']`?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can't share variables reliably in Django because your web server will almost certainly use multiple processes. Use an external key-value store like Redis.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, if the last two modules `a` and `z` are not reading GLOB at build time, but at runtime, would it work reliably? So, that said, instead of `A_GLOB`, I use some function to read GLOB at runtime only.

Comment: I'm not sure of the distinction you're making, Python doesn't have an explicit build step. The problem is that variables are not shared across processes.

Answer (score 0):

All integers allowed to do with modulus `%`. and result of modulus is not boolean, but an integer also. So you need to more specific.

```
A_GLOB = [k for k in GLOB if GLOB[k]%2 != 0] # 1%2 and 3%2 == 1

Z_GLOB = [k for k in GLOB if not GLOB[k]%2 == 0] # 2%2 == 0
```

Comment: Dude, you know that I was asking about Python, right?... 0 is regarded as False.